# How do I uninstall the Apple Mail app and reinstall it?

Tags: mail.app

How do I uninstall Apple Mail app on a Macbook Pro and then reinstall it?

Comment: What do you wan't to acheive?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me.

Answer (score 1):

**To uninstall** try with AppCleaner, it's free in the AppStore.
Apple Mail is a system app so, in AppCleaner, try *double click on the checkbox* and then proceed to *Delete* the app.

**For Reinstall.**
Apparently you'll need to do a reinstallation of OSX.
According to [this Apple page](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph11201?locale=en_US), a reinstallation wont affect your files, can't tell for myself, I've never done that. 
Simply **make a backup before anything** and may the force be with you.

**[OSX Reinstallation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)**

1. Reboot your Mac and hold the COMMAND + R keys while rebooting.
2. You will enter to Recovery environment.
3. Choose reinstall.

Comment: Will AppCleaner remove all Mail's files? or just those in usual places (i.e. ~/Library/Mail is unusual) and will it remove files for all users?

Comment: I'm not sure. Make a backup of all your mail folders before you proceed. (Inbox, VIPS, Stared, Junk..etc) **1. cmd click on each folder to select them 2.Go to _Mailbox menu_ -> _Backup Mailbox_ **

Comment: So how do you know this answer is correct?

Comment: Proceed with **caution**, I've never done this before, This is just my suggestion of what i would do in your case.

Comment: AppCleaner searches for all files related to the app. So it is almost for sure that it will delete all Mail's files.

Comment: How does it do that? so will it pick up ~/Library/Mail and ~/Library/Preferences files for all users?